# MySQL - Get count of users that have a "user-contact"

Tags: mysql, join, count

Consider the three tables in the following Schema **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb1846)**.

- This mini-model represents a simple example of a database I'm working on .
- The **Users** table has 4 attributes, the user_id (primary key auto_increment), the country_id which is a foreign key referencing the **Country** table, the user_msisdn which is the phone number of the user, and the username.
- The **Contacts** table has 3 attributes, the contact_id (primary key auto_increment), the user_id which is a foreign key referencing the **Users** table, and the contact_msisdn which is the user contact's phone numbers (the phone numbers on your phone contacts list).
- The relation between the **Users** table and the **Contacts** table is many-to-many, a user can have many contacts, and a contact can be found in any user's contacts list.

**Requirements:**
For each country, get the count of users that have at least one "user-contact", where a "user-contact" is a contact that is a user, and the count of users that don't have any "user-contact".
**E.g.,** For country = 'Sweden' (country_id = 3), the user_id = 3 has two contacts in the **Contacts** table that are considered "user-contact" with (msisdn = '+220011223344' & '+224433221100'). So the query results that I want: Sweden has 1 user (user_id = 3) that has at least one "user-contact" and zero users that have no "user-contact", and so on for each country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.country_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN u2.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN u.user_id END) as has_contact_that_is_user ,
       COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN u2.user_id is null AND u.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN u.user_id END) as has_no_contact_that_is_user 
FROM Country c
LEFT JOIN users u
 ON(c.country_id = u.country_id)
LEFT JOIN contacts co
 ON(co.user_id = u.user_id)
LEFT JOIN Users u2
 ON(u2.user_msisdn = co.contact_msisdn)
 GROUP BY c.country_id
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb1846/30)**

Comment: The Query results are saying that "United States of America" with country_id = 1 has ( has_contact = 1 & no_contact = 1), in fact, it should result (has_contact = 0, and no_contact = 2), since the 3 contacts of user_id = 1 in the Contacts table aren't users at the same time.
So, the true results say that the contact of the user should also be a user.

Comment: better naming of the counts: has_contact_that_is_user & has_no_contact_that_is_user